# miniconda won't manage the python env since macOS Catalina

Tags: python, macos-catalina, miniconda

Ever since I upgraded to macOS Catalina, conda is not managing the environment properly. I ran `which python`, regardless whether I have activated a conda environment or not, it will always point to `/usr/bin/python`:

without conda

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

with conda base environment

```
$ conda activate
(base) $ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

with some other conda environment

```
$ conda env create -f whatup_environment.yml
... 
(whatup) $ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

I checked and saw that `/usr/bin/python` is a symbolic link pointing to python 2.7 which comes with the operating system.

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Nov 20 19:27 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

It feels like conda lost the ability to control the environment. I was originally using anaconda, and also tried uninstalling that and now installed `miniconda`. The problem persists.

**Anyone else running into the same issue and have a solution?**

---

Other stuffs that I've tried.

I saw that Apple [migrates from `bash` to `zsh`](https://www.theverge.com/2019/6/4/18651872/apple-macos-catalina-zsh-bash-shell-replacement-features). So I also tried this too:

```
conda init zsh
```

apart from

```
conda init bash
```

There are also some [post](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-restore-anaconda-after-macos-catalina-update/) about Apple move files to the `Relocated Items` folder. I double checked there too and makes sure conda was not moved there by the OS. That's also why I tried to uninstall/reinstall.

```
$ which conda
/Users/my_name/miniconda3/condabin/conda
```

---

Edit:

Another interesting thing that I noticed is that there is an integrated terminal in the PyCharm IDE. And over there, things are working fine.

[image]

Not sure if it is related. But if anyone can else the discrepancy between them, it would be great too.

Comment: I checked, and I'm not having this issue. I had no idea Catalina was messing with Anaconda for some people. This is strange as hell.